# For a supersingular elliptic curve, $Hom_{\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}}(E, E^1)$ is free module of rank 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, finite-fields

Let $E$ be a non-supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $E^1$ be some elliptic curve, then $Hom_{\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}}(E, E^1)$ is free $\mathbb{Z}$ module of rank 2.

Can someone explain this please? I can't see how it is of rank 2.

Comment: This is true if the module is nonzero, but if $E$ and $E^1$ are nonisogenous than this module vanishes (more or less by definition).

Comment: Yes, But, how it is of rank 2, please explain. I cant see that

Comment: See for example Silverman's *The arithmetic of elliptic curves*, **Thm. V.3.1**.

Comment: See p.162 of [Silverman's book](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf) the rank of $End(E)$ is $2$ or $4$, and rank $4$ is the definition of super-singular elliptic curve over a finite field. Using the dual isogeny, you get a ($\mathbb{Z}$-module) embedding of $Hom(E,E') $ into $End(E)$.

Comment: p.91 , corollary III.7.5, of Silverman book says that $Hom(E,E^1)$ is free of rank 4. its not the rank for supersingular.

Comment: However, p.162 v.3.2.2 make a sense.But, nonsupersingular elliptic curves , over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ are order in imaginary guadratic field. That is for endomorphism ring. im not clear how to embed it in to $Hom(E,E^1)$, Thank you very much

Comment: Use @reuns to notify me. And instead of asking 2 questions per days, read Silverman's book and take some notes. Then explain what you know  and why you are stuck at showing something, with the pages references and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there is a non-zero isogeny $\phi:E\to E'$. Let $q$ be a power of $p$ so that both $E'$ and $\phi$ are defined over $\mathbb F_q$. Let $F_q:E'\to E'$ be the $q$-power Frobenius map. Then $\text{Hom}(E,E')$ at least contains $\{m\phi+n F_q\circ\phi: m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$, so the rank is at least 2. I'll let you figure out why the rank can't be greater than 2.

Comment: Since you literally wrote the book on this I half expected that your answer would be a page reference to TAoEC . . .

Comment: @joe   Thank you for the answer, What did you meant by $F_q$, I am sorry I can't see how it cant\'t be greater than 2.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies What is TAoEC ?

Comment: @student  Sorry, $F_q$ is the $q$-power Frobenius map. I'll edit the answer to fix that typo. As for TAoEC in Elkies answers, that's my book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, so he was just joking that I could have simply given you a reference there, instead of writing out an answer. As for why the rank can't be 4 when E is ordinary, that should follow from the material in Chapter V (Sections 3 and 4) of the aforementioned book.

Comment: I am so happy that, I could communicate with you and prof. Elkies. @JoeSilverman , Professor, I am doing my thesis on "Algorithms for Elliptic Curves" at TU Kaiserslautern, Germany. Is there any way to find Atkin's "The Number of Points on an Elliptic Curve Modulo a Prime"  article? Thank you very much.